# A Href onclick update value

Tags: javascript, php, html

How to update the value in shopping cart when someone input the promocode and click apply (using href) without redirect to another page using php and javascript? pls help. Thank you

My code :

```
<td colspan="2" align="left"><input style="width:200px;" type="text" name="_PromoCode" placeholder="Insert Promo Code" maxlength="20" /></td>
<td align="left"><a href=# onclick="return get_promo();">apply</a></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><font color="#FF0000"><?php echo $hasil['Currency_ID'];?></font></td>
<td><font color="#FF0000"><?php echo "<span id='promocode' style='float:right'>". number_format($total_promo)."</span>";?></font></td>
```

script :

```
<script>

function get_promo()
{
    var x = <?php echo $total_promo ?> ;

    document.getElementById("promocode").innerHTML = formatNumber(x);

}

</script>
```

screenshot :
[image]

Comment: You might be able to implement something like this smoothly with AJAX. Checkout some documentation: http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/ajax_intro.asp and http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Christ, I prefer javascript than AJAX, Newbie here..

Comment: AJAX is a part of javascript... You need AJAX

Comment: @Joe AJAX is javascript, you should check out some beginner AJAX tutorials.

Comment: can someone post the example for me? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If youre getting the promo code from a database such as mysql. I suggest you do an AJAX call within your javascript code to a PHP script that will retreive the promo code information and update the total and such. With ajax you have the ability to not redirect to another page or refresh the current page.

Comment: odannyc, can you give the example plz. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use `Ajax` for this kind of operation.
You can send and receive the processed data to the page without refreshing it.

You can find more help for beginners using `AJAX` can see here

[Ajax using jquery and php beginners help tutorial Link](http://webdevelopingcat.com/jquery-php-beginner-tutorial-ajax/)